# Navbar menu for phone format in Vue works in dev mode, but not after build?

Tags: vue.js

Application with navbar menu works in dev mod, phone format, but after I build it and put it on website it can’t be expanded.

Comment: More details are needed, the question is too open

Comment: did it work in prod mode in your local? put in your website in dev mode and check if it works correctly there too

Comment: No, when I build it, it doesn't work

Comment: I used adjusted bootstrap navbar in my app. In dev mode everything worked well, on every screen format. When I built it, large screen works, but on phone not. On phone format you get hamburger menu, but you can't open it.